# Why my images is not showing from firebase firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application where i am uploading multiple images with 4 edittexts to the firebase then I am trying to retrieve the data to the recyclerview now my editext's data is retrieving but the data of images is not showing in reyclerview.

**my adapter code**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position)
{


    holder.name.setText(datalist.get(position).getName());
    holder.email.setText(datalist.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.desc.setText(datalist.get(position).getDesc());
    holder.book.setText(datalist.get(position).getBook());

    Glide.with(context).load(datalist.get(position).getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);


}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datalist.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView name, email, desc, book;
    ImageView imageView;
    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_email);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_desc);
        book = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_book);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `datalist.get(position).getImage()` return?

Comment: sir datalist is array in which the data is returning from firebase and getimage is method of model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment session you mentioned, **getImage()** is an array then, How it will load the image you need to pass a particular image in the array?

Let's suppose, If you want to load the first image in an array use the below code -

```
if(!wishlist_models.get(position).getImage().isEmpty()) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(wishlist_models.get(position).getImage()get(0))
            .into(holder.wishlist_image);
    }
```